# Speech: long_running_recognize on serverless

Tags: google-cloud-python

I would like to use long_running_recognize with on serverless. I have a constraint that I can only run for 5 minutes at a time. In order to gather a transcription which takes longer than 5 minutes, I would like to resume the `operation.result` call in a new process.

To do this I need to serialize the operation and create a new instance of it in the new process.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: solution here https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/6162